# "wordpress error in establishing database connection" and missing tables

Tags: database, errors

I received this message when trying to enter any page of the site, wp-admin included.

> "wordpress error in establishing database connection"

It also says that some table may be missing, and I discovered wpshop_blogs and wpshop_usermeta are actually missing from database. What to do now? Even the backups are missing this table. I can't access the WordPress admin panel and I do not have any backup with the tables.

I double cheked my database connections credentials and they are correct.

When i try to access the admin panel of wordpress, this is what i get (i know it is in italian but it is basically sayings that it could not find the wpshop_blogs table): [image]

Comment: You double check your database credentials? Even if tables are missing, that shouldn't prevent a database connection.

Comment: Yes of course, i should have specified this in the question

Comment: is it possible your host changed some of the credentials? hostname perhaps?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/179607)

Comment: the credentials in wp-config.php are all correct...i called the host client service and we checked togheter but they do not give me any other clue or direction to fix the problem

Comment: please check url : https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Comment: thanks for the link. Given that my credential are correct, i tried to change the password manually, with an sql command, but i got an error message : #1044 - Access denied for user 'Sql1106766'@'%' to database 'mysql'. I then asked the host to change my password; will update the post when they do this.